# Matlab demonstration of similar matrices

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

i know there two matrix are similar if there exist some matrix $P$ such that following relationship holds

$B=P^{-1}*A*P$

if   given  matrix $A$ has Eigenvector  $x$ and eigenvalue $\lambda$ , so that we have

$A*x=\lambda*x$
then    similar matrices have same eigenvalue if

$B*x=P^{-1}*A*P *x=\lambda*x$  and  multiply  left side by $P$ we will get

$B*x=A*(P*x)=\lambda*(P*x)$

so that means that if we have  eigenvalue decomposition  of  $A$, then eigenvector of  $B$ will be given matrix $P$ times eigenvector of matrix $A$, but following matlab  commands dont  confirm this fact

```
> A=[2 1 3; 4 1  5;6 0 1];
M=rand(3);
B=inv(M)*A*M;
[V,D]=eig(A)
[V1,D1]=eig(B)

V =

    0.4626    0.3333   -0.1191
    0.7432    0.6667   -0.9042
    0.4834   -0.6667    0.4102


D =

    6.7417         0         0
         0   -2.0000         0
         0         0   -0.7417


V1 =

    0.5772   -0.6858    0.6245
   -0.7967    0.7273   -0.7552
   -0.1792   -0.0248    0.1992


D1 =

    6.7417         0         0
         0   -0.7417         0
         0         0   -2.0000

>> M*V

ans =

    1.2263    0.8651   -0.9221
    0.6375    0.0949   -0.2846
    1.4864    0.2466   -0.4635

>>
```

what is the reason of this ?

Comment: I find your last sentence very hard to understand. Are you simply forgetting that it is $P^{-1}Bx$ and not just $Bx$?

Comment: i see thanks in advance